# How to make a constrained extension of Collection generic in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, functional-programming

**Context**

I have a class `Profile` which conforms to protocol `Entity`. I am also adding a search method to all `Swift Collections` where the Element is a `Profile`.

However, I would like to make this generic to support not only `Profile` but every object conforming to `Entity`.

---

**Code**

```swift
protocol Entity {
    var name: String { get }
}

class Profile: Entity { ... }

extension Collection where Element == Profile {
    func searched(with search: String) -> [Profile] {
        guard !(search.isEmpty) else { return self }
        return self.filter { ($0.name.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased())) }
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

How can I make the search method generic to support all objects conforming to `Entity`?

Comment: Just replace `Element == Profile` with `Element: Entity`. This is clearly explained in the [Swift language manual](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/GenericParametersAndArguments.html).

Comment: Not related to your question but there is a method called `localizedStandardContains` that is diacritics and case insensitive. `$0.name.localizedStandardContains(search)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you should change the extension to the below code

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element: Entity
```

next, change the return type of the method to

```
func searched(with search: String) -> [Iterator.Element]
```

Finally, the extension can be like this:

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element: Entity {
        func searched(with search: String) -> [Iterator.Element] {
            guard !(search.isEmpty) else { return [Iterator.Element]() }
            return self.filter { ($0.name.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased())) }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this solved the problem. The only open question is, how to return the given Collection without a filter as an Array when `search.isEmpty`, instead of returning an empty Array.

Comment: you're welcome, you can convert self to [Iterator.Element] like this: return self as! [Self.Element]

Comment: Does this also work, when the object the `searched` method is called on, is a `FetchedResults` or is the force casting causes a crash then?

Comment: There is a probability that it will crash in general mode. but in this case, the crash does not happen because you are sure of the cast type and it same with the constraint of extension.

Comment: it is actually crashing when force casting. I constrained the extension to all Collection types but try to force cast to an Array. So as far as I know, this should crash whenever the given collection type is not an Array itself.

Comment: Oh I didn't pay attention to collection and you are right, I think we can convert the collection to Array like this: Array(self)